# Material-UI, React, Cards del mismo tamaño

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aplicación-web, jsx, material-ui

apenas estoy aprendiendo react y puede ser que por eso no tenga el conocimiento aun para hacer algo tan simple, y tengo la siguiente pagina, es un grid de material ui, con su card, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero lograr que cada card sea del mismo tamaño, sin excepción, mas no se como lograrlo, el código es el siguiente:

```js
import React from 'react';
import audio from '../../assets/imgs/audio.png';
import docs from '../../assets/imgs/docs.png';
import otro from '../../assets/imgs/otro.png';
import video from '../../assets/imgs/video.png';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import LaunchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Launch';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';


import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

const cardUseStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardGrid: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(8),
    
  },
  card: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    
  },
  cardMedia: {
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
    
  },
  cardContent:{
    maxHeight: '100%',
    maxWidth: '100%',
  },
  
  
}));


export const MultimediaCard = (multi) => {
  //["Audio", "Documento", "Imagen", "Infografía", "Vídeo", "Otro"]
  let image;
  const description = (!multi.description ? 'Sin descripcion' : multi.description);

  switch (multi.type) {
    case 'Audio':
      image = audio;
      break;
    case 'Documento':
      image = docs;
      break;
    case 'Imagen':
      image = multi.link;
      break;
    case 'Infografía':
      image = multi.link;
      break;

    case 'Vídeo':
      image = video;
      break;
    default:
      image = otro;
      break;
  }

  const cardClasses = cardUseStyles();

  return (

    <div className='card-item'>
       <Container className={cardClasses.cardGrid}>
          {/* End hero unit */}
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
        
              <Grid key={multi.id} >
                <Card className={cardClasses.card}>
                  <CardMedia
                    className={cardClasses.cardMedia}
                    image={image}
                    title="Image title"
                  />
                  <CardContent className={cardClasses.cardContent}>
                    <Typography variant="h4">
                      {multi.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                      {multi.type}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary" href={multi.link} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer">
                      View
                    </Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary">
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
           
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      

    </div>

  );
}
```

he intentando modificar la sección `cardContent` en el `cardUseStyles` por eso lleva un `maxWidth` y un `maxHeight` al 100%, pero no lo logro, se que es en esa seccion de `cardContent` porque si le cambio el color del background a rojo la seccion se torna roja, a menos que este equivocado ya que estoy algo perdido, alguien que me pueda guiar para que todos estos sean del mismo tamaño, gracias

Comment: Prueba añadir un height al grid, cuando usas el porcentaje algún parent debe tener un height determinado.

Comment: sip eso era, gracias